# Collection#find: pass a function instead ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am very new to node.js and I am making a Discord bot. I am trying to make a ticket system using `djs-ticketsystem` and it is giving me this error: `(node:15168) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead`

```js
const ticketsystem = require("djs-ticketsystem");

bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.content == '-new') {

        ticketsystem.createTicket({
            name: 'new-ticket',
            category: 'TICKETS',
            owner: message.author,
            roles: [
                'Owner',
                'Support'
            ],
            openmessage: 'Creating your ticket...',
            ticketmessage: 'Thank-you for creating a ticket!',
            messagelinker: message
        }).catch(err => {
            message.reply('Failed to create a new ticket.')
        });

    };
});
```

Comment: When you look at the warning message can you find the line of code that causes it? Try to figure out whether your code, `discord.js`, or `djs-ticketsystem` is causing  warning.

Comment: Your error is most likely caused by `djs-ticketsystem` it has not been updated in over a year and discord.js has changed a lot since then, including when it comes to the `find()` method that's causing you the error, `djs-ticketsystem` is probably doing `find(Channel_ID)` which is deprecated now and needs to be as follows: `find(channel => channel.id === Channel_ID)`